# How to access a variable outside of function in Django

Tags: python, html, django

How would I access myvar outside of the page function. I am able to print myvar when I have print(myvar) inside the page function, but not when it is outside.

```
def page(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        myvar = form.cleaned_data.get("myvar")
        # myvar is printed here
        print(myvar)
        if not myvar:
            myvar = "this"
        instance.myvar= myvar
        instance.save()
    context = {
        "form" : form
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)

# I want to print the contents of myvar but it doesn't work here
print(myvar)
```

Thanks

Comment: myvar does not exist outside of that function, and even if it did you cannot possibly be running any code there to print it. You had better explain what you are really trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to get the text that was input into the charfield on home.html, and use that text in a python function.

Comment: Can you post the function?

Comment: I have a variable in the function, lets call the variable v1, and I want v1 to equal myvar which is the text that was input into the charfield in home.html.  I hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: I suppose I can merge my other function with page so that I can use the variable myvar in that function.

Comment: You don't have to merge the function, you can call it from `page` and pass myvar to it.

Comment: Can you explain what prevents you from putting `print(myvar) ` just before `return`, INSIDE the function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about the request/response cycle here. As I said in the comment, even if this was allowed by Python scoping rules, what would call your function? The request is over and has returned.

If you need this, you would have to call the function yourself from inside the view, and pass your value to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You should read [Python scope rules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

If you would insist on doing it, you'd have to use a global `myvar`. Something along these lines

```
myvar = None

def myfn(args):
    global myvar

    myvar = "z"

print myvar
```

although this is not advisable.

Also, the `print(myvar)` statement will only run once when importing the module, so most probably won't do what you want.

Comment: Don't recommend this. Globals are even more dangerous than in normal Python code here, since they would be shared by all requests.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know, that's why the "this is not advisable". Besides that, he should read about scopes and know that "global" exists.

Answer (score -1):

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import request

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html',{"name":"Box Culvert Structural Analysis Design and Detailing Tool"})

num1=request.GET['h']
num2=request.GET['ts']

def add(num1,num2):
    result=num1+num2
    return render('results.html',{'result':result})
```